# Proving Fermat's last theorem with n=3 using $\mathbb{Z}[w]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've been trying to find a proof for Fermat's last theorem with exponent n = 3 using unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[w]$ where $w$ is a primitive third root of unity ( solution of  $x^3$ - 1 ). I presume it's in Edwards book on Fermat's Last Theorem but I don't have access to it unfortunately.

Would anyone know where I could find a proof online or be able to provide one? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: There is [this](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/07/proof-for-n3-using-eisenstein-integers.html)

Comment: See my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_47_alg_num.pdf), introduction.

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4083254/413677), although I'm not sure if it is correct.